# Ruby on Rails - first application - didn't create index.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello im starting with RoR and i already have a problem :/.

My rails version is 4.0.0 and ruby 1.8.7.

When i using rails new blog command i have something like this:

```
`create  
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/assets/images/.keep
  create  app/mailers/.keep
  create  app/models/.keep
  create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
  create  app/models/concerns/.keep
  create  bin
  create  bin/bundle
  create  bin/rails
  create  bin/rake
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.keep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.keep
  create  log
  create  log/.keep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.keep
  create  test/controllers
  create  test/controllers/.keep
  create  test/mailers
  create  test/mailers/.keep
  create  test/models
  create  test/models/.keep
  create  test/helpers
  create  test/helpers/.keep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.keep
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
     run  bundle install`
```

As you can see command didn't create public/index.html file ? Why.

I'm following this tutorial: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Command rails server work well i think:

```
michal@michal:~/rails/blog$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on `http://0.0.0.0 :3000`
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2013-08-02 19:46:54] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-08-02 19:46:54] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2011-10-30) [x86_64-linux]
[2013-08-02 19:46:54] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=16218 port=3000
^C[2013-08-02 19:47:03] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2013-08-02 19:47:03] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
```

Comment: as of 4 it doesn't create index.html anymore, as it is now dynamic to give you more information about the current runtime environment.

Comment: Off topic, but important: You should use at least ruby 1.9.3 with ror 4. Much better is ruby 2.0. 1.8 is not supported anymore I think.

Comment: Take a look at the output of the server: `INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2011-10-30) [x86_64-linux]`, it is using 1.9.3, not 1.8.7 like @michal said

Answer (score 2):

The index.html file was removed from new Rails apps as of 4.0.0.

The pull request and discussion related to this is [on Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8468).

In short, it was felt that not having to make users delete the index.html file to make their app work initially made learning Rails easier. The dynamic replacement page also provides better information than the static page did.